# Azure AD ADAL in MVC Application - Token Expiration

Tags: azure, authentication, model-view-controller, access-token, adal

I have created a Web Application using Azure AD for authentication.
The Access Token expires after one hour (by default).
Since my Application mainly uses Telerik Controls it doesn't do any full page roundtrips to the server. 
To refresh the token I have implemented a JavaScript countdown.
I have tried different approaches

1. Insert a hidden IFrame and refresh the content of the IFrame with a page inside my app before the  token expires
2. Insert a hidden IFrame and refresh the content of the IFrame with the Microsoft logon link like described in this Microsoft article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-v2-protocols-implicit
3. Open a Temporary window with the Microsoft logon link
4. I also took a look inside the ADAL JavaScript Library here: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/tree/dev
   but this would mean I have to rebuild the whole application

All approaches did not work. Even worse: If i do a full page refresh by hitting F5 in the browser, approximately 5 minutes before the token expires, the page does not load anymore and the "loading" circle in the browser is spinning endlessly.

Does anybody have a working approach how to deal with ADAL access tokens in MVC?

This is the code to configure my authentication

```
 public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions() { CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always });

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    ClientId = clientId,
                    Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/",

                    TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        // instead of using the default validation (validating against a single issuer value, as we do in line of business apps (single tenant apps)), 
                        // we turn off validation
                        //
                        // NOTE:
                        // * In a multitenant scenario you can never validate against a fixed issuer string, as every tenant will send a different one.
                        // * If you don’t care about validating tenants, as is the case for apps giving access to 1st party resources, you just turn off validation.
                        // * If you do care about validating tenants, think of the case in which your app sells access to premium content and you want to limit access only to the tenant that paid a fee, 
                        //       you still need to turn off the default validation but you do need to add logic that compares the incoming issuer to a list of tenants that paid you, 
                        //       and block access if that’s not the case.
                        // * Refer to the following sample for a custom validation logic: https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-WebAPI-MultiTenant-OpenIdConnect-DotNet

                        ValidateIssuer = false
                    },

                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                    {
                        // If there is a code in the OpenID Connect response, redeem it for an access token and refresh token, and store those away. 
                        AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
                        {
                            var code = context.Code;

                            ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
                            string tenantID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;
                            string signInUserId = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

                            AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(string.Format("{0}/{1}", "https://login.microsoftonline.com", tenantID), new ADALTokenCache(signInUserId));

                            // Get the access token for AAD Graph. Doing this will also initialize the token cache associated with the authentication context
                            // In theory, you could acquire token for any service your application has access to here so that you can initialize the token cache
                            AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, "https://graph.windows.net");

                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        },

                        RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
                        {
                            // This ensures that the address used for sign in and sign out is picked up dynamically from the request
                            // this allows you to deploy your app (to Azure Web Sites, for example)without having to change settings
                            // Remember that the base URL of the address used here must be provisioned in Azure AD beforehand.
                            string appBaseUrl = context.Request.Scheme + "://" + context.Request.Host + context.Request.PathBase;
                            context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = appBaseUrl + "/";
                            context.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = appBaseUrl;

                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        },

                        AuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                        {
                            // Suppress the exception if you don't want to see the error
                            context.HandleResponse();
                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        }
                    }

                });
        }
```

This is the code in my BaseController to refresh the token before it expires. I monitor the Token Expiration client side and call this method before the Token expires:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult RefreshAuthenticationToken()
{
    var refreshToken = DirectoryUserRepository.GetTokenForApplication().Result.RefreshToken;
    var newToken = DirectoryUserRepository.RefreshToken(refreshToken);
    return Json(new { TokenExpirationTimestampUTC = newToken.ExpiresOn.GetUnixTimestamp() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Here are the other missing methods

```
public async Task<AuthenticationToken> GetTokenForApplication()
        {
            string signedInUserID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
            string tenantID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;
            string userObjectID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;

            // get a token for the Graph without triggering any user interaction (from the cache, via multi-resource refresh token, etc)
            ClientCredential clientcred = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
            // initialize AuthenticationContext with the token cache of the currently signed in user, as kept in the app's database
            AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(aadInstance + tenantID, new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));
            try
            {

                var authenticationResult = await authenticationContext
                    .AcquireTokenSilentAsync(
                  graphResourceID,
                  new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey),
                  new UserIdentifier(userObjectID, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));
                return new AuthenticationToken(authenticationResult.AccessToken) { ExpiresOn = authenticationResult.ExpiresOn, RefreshToken = authenticationResult.RefreshToken };

                //return authenticationResult.AccessToken;

            }
            catch (AggregateException e)
            {
                foreach (Exception inner in e.InnerExceptions)
                {
                    if (!(inner is AdalException)) continue;
                    if (((AdalException)inner).ErrorCode == AdalError.FailedToAcquireTokenSilently)
                    {
                        authenticationContext.TokenCache.Clear();
                    }
                }
                throw e.InnerException;
            }
            catch (AdalException exception)
            {
                if (exception.ErrorCode == AdalError.FailedToAcquireTokenSilently)
                {
                    authenticationContext.TokenCache.Clear();
                    throw;
                }
                return null;
            }
        }



  public AuthenticationToken RefreshToken(string refreshToken)
        {
            string signedInUserID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
            string tenantID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;

            // get a token for the Graph without triggering any user interaction (from the cache, via multi-resource refresh token, etc)
            ClientCredential clientcred = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
            // initialize AuthenticationContext with the token cache of the currently signed in user, as kept in the app's database
            AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(aadInstance + tenantID, new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));
            try
            {

                var authenticationResult = authenticationContext
                    .AcquireTokenByRefreshToken(
                    refreshToken,
                    clientcred,
                    graphResourceID);
                return new AuthenticationToken(authenticationResult.AccessToken) { ExpiresOn = authenticationResult.ExpiresOn, RefreshToken = authenticationResult.RefreshToken };
            }
            catch (AggregateException e)
            {
                foreach (Exception inner in e.InnerExceptions)
                {
                    if (!(inner is AdalException)) continue;
                    if (((AdalException)inner).ErrorCode == AdalError.FailedToAcquireTokenSilently)
                    {
                        authenticationContext.TokenCache.Clear();
                    }
                }
                throw e.InnerException;
            }
            catch (AdalException exception)
            {
                if (exception.ErrorCode == AdalError.FailedToAcquireTokenSilently)
                {
                    authenticationContext.TokenCache.Clear();
                    throw;
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The are two kinds of access tokens we can use from a web application to call the web API.

The first is that using delegated User identity with OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Grant flow. The second is that using application identity with OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials Grant flow.

When we use the delegated user token, we can refresh the token via the web application server side then the token is expired.

And if you using the application identity to acquire the token, we can get the access token again using the app's credential.

> Since my Application mainly uses Telerik Controls it doesn't do any full page roundtrips to the server.

Did you mean that the control using AJAX to receive the data? If I understood correctly, we can develop an proxy in MVC application to acquire the data. And in the proxy service, we can renew the token when the token is expired.

Here is a figure about the flow of web application call the web API:

[image]

### Update(refresh the access token via HTTP request)

```
 public static void RefreshToken(string refreshToken)
 {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        string clientId = "{clientId}";
        string secret = "{secret}";
        string resource = "https://graph.windows.net";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append($"client_id={clientId}");
        sb.Append($"&grant_type=refresh_token");
        sb.Append($"&client_secret={secret}");
        sb.Append($"&resource={resource}");
        sb.Append($"&refresh_token={refreshToken}");

        HttpContent bodyContent = new StringContent(sb.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        var tokenResponse = client.PostAsync("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token", bodyContent).Result;
        var stringResponse = tokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(stringResponse);
        Console.WriteLine(jObject["access_token"].Value<string>());
 }
```

Comment: Yes, the controls use AJAX to get data from the controllers

Comment: In this scenario,  you can build a endpoint to exchange the token for the web app. Or you can create an web API proxy, you can handle it automatically if the token is expired.

Comment: I have edited my initial post and added the code now... I do the following, I monitor the token validity client side. If the token is about to expire I do an Ajax request to refresh the token on the server side. But even after Token refresh the client does not get the new token. The cookie holding the token information is not refreshed. Even if I put a hidden IFrame on my page and do a request to refresh the token ... it still expires.

Comment: The code above will get the token from cache and try to refresh the token when the token is expired. To force refreshing the token, we can make the request directly. I have appended the code in the post.

Comment: 'm using same data like in the entire solution (I read them from web.config). In the response i get the error message: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS70002: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_secret or client_assertion'.\r\nTrace ID: 5f78ed97-542b-4f10-a7ea-bc6f0daef1f5\r\nCorrelation ID: 890f78b9-4992-4218-bc75-da260a6b50c1\r\nTimestamp: 2017-01-04 12:55:30Z","error_codes":[70002],"timestamp":"2017-01-04 12:55:30Z","trace_id":"5f78ed97-542b-4f10-a7ea-bc6f0daef1f5","correlation_id":"890f78b9-4992-4218-bc75-da260a6b50c1"}. Am I missing something

Comment: Plus I think this does not update the cookie on the client. Thereby the call of Controller Methods secured by [Authorize] won't work. Am I right? I am using the web browser / web application scenario like here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#web-browser-to-web-application . This scenario implies that the token expires after one hour. What I need to do is to refresh the authentication token in a way that also updates the cookie on the client.

Comment: For the **invalid_client** issue, we need to provide the `client_secret`(app's key). Please ensure you have passed this parameter when you refresh the access token. And the cookies are different with the token, since it is a new problem different described by the orignal post, I suggest that you reopen a new thread if you wants to update the cookies on the client.

Comment: Hi, I provided the client_secret (same like defined in web.config and used through the entire application) but I still get the "invalid_client" error.

Comment: I made a stupid mistake... All data - including Client secret but except refresh token - MUST be URL-Encoded. Otherwise I get an Unauthorized Error resulting in Invalid_Client Error Message. Thanks much.